# upload file module path angularJs nodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, path

Hello I create an upload. everything works perfectly well I upload files ms and I manage to get the path. However I copy my back chemain to replace a file with the method replaces but I am having a problem. Under window my way tmp\image.jpg is there a solution for the path becomes tmp/image.jpg ?
I use currently path.join Module

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var pathString = 'tmp\image.jpg';
pathString = pathString.replace(/\\/g,"/");
```

Comment: thank ! but, there is no automatic function for I intend to install the application on linux and window ? thanks !

Comment: Oups, sorry it's good :) thank ! and I have a other little problem with the path.join :var urlCopy = path.join('.','app','template','templates',req.body.template); it's ok it's working but this :
                var urlPast = path.join('.','diapo',req.body.diapo, req.body.id); I have a error : Must be a string why ?

Comment: @coco62 welcome, this error happens because `req.body.id` is not a string